# How to get Euler angles from two transforms in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript, euler-angles

I have a `Transform` that is rotated by an angle on an axis. Is it possible to get the Euler angles for the rotation using the `Transform` before rotation and the `Transform` after rotation? I tried using `Transform.basis.get_euler()`, to get the Euler angles of the `Transform` before and after. However I don't think subtracting them would work. How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

I came up with this:

```
var A := start.basis.get_rotation_quat()
var B := end.basis.get_rotation_quat()
var R := A.inverse() * B
print(R.get_euler())
```

*It is also recommended to always `normalize` quaternions to minimize cumulative floating point errors. But I believe it is not a problem here.*

---

### Explanation

The idea is that you have a rotation quaternion `A` that after some rotation `R` becomes `B`. In other words:

```
B = A * R
```

And if we solve for `R`, we get this:

```
B = A * R

B * R.inverse() = A * R * R.inverse()

B * R.inverse() = A

B.inverse() * B * R.inverse() = B.inverse() * A

R.inverse() = B.inverse() * A

R = (B.inverse() * A).inverse()

R = A.inverse() * B
```

---

### Testing

This is what I came up for testing it:

```
tool
extends MeshInstance


func _enter_tree() -> void:
    set_notify_transform(true)


func _notification(what: int) -> void:
    if what == NOTIFICATION_TRANSFORM_CHANGED:
        var parent := get_parent() as Spatial
        var end := global_transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
        var start := parent.global_transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
        var A := start
        var B := end
        var R := A.inverse() * B
        var S := transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
        if R.w < 0: R = -R
        if S.w < 0: S = -S
        if not S.is_equal_approx(R):
            prints("FAIL", rotation_degrees, R, S)
```

Attach it to a `MeshInstance` child of an `Spatial`.

The code will run on the editor. It enables a notification for any change in its `Transform`. When it get the notification, it computes the quaternion from its `global_transform` and its parent `global_transform`. Rotate it around and see it if prints.

By the way, I had initially forgot that there are two ways to represent the same rotation with quaternions. So it wasn't passing the test. These lines fix it:

```
if R.w < 0: R = -R
if S.w < 0: S = -S
```

*No, `normalize` does not fix this. And the lack of `normalize` didn't cause the test to fail either.*

I also tested that you don't need to do that to get the correct value from `get_euler`. I mean, like this it works correctly:

```
var end := global_transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
var start := parent.global_transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
var A := start
var B := end
var R := A.inverse() * B
var S := transform.basis.get_rotation_quat()
if not S.get_euler().is_equal_approx(R.get_euler()):
    prints("FAIL", rotation_degrees, R, S)
```

Similarly it works correctly with `Transform` directly, like this:

```
var end := global_transform
var start := parent.global_transform
var A := start
var B := end
var R := A.affine_inverse() * B
var S := transform
if not S.is_equal_approx(R):
    prints("FAIL", rotation_degrees, R, S)
```